# How to pass parameters for a managed code dll in installshield?

Tags: c#, installshield

I have a dotnet script which is for encryption and decryption. I have to pass the parameters for the setvalues function in installshield. How can I achieve this? Dotnet code is as follows. I have the assembly (.dll) file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Security;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace EncryptionDecryption
{
    public class EncrptionHelper
    {
        #region Member variables      
        static byte[] entropy = { 0, 8, 2, 3, 5 };
        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        public static void SetValue(string configFilePathName, string appSettingKey, string appSettingValue)
        {
            appSettingValue = EncryptString(ToSecureString(appSettingValue));
            SetSetting(appSettingKey, appSettingValue, configFilePathName);
        }

        public static string GetValue(string configFilePathName, string appSettingKey)
        {
            string value = GetSetting(appSettingKey, configFilePathName);           
            value = ToInsecureString( DecryptString(value));
            return value;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Methods
        private static bool SetSetting(string Key, string Value, string configFilePath)
        {
            bool result = false;
            try
            {
               // System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configFilePath);
              //  config.AppSettings.File = configFilePath;
               // config.AppSettings.Settings[Key].Value = Value;     
               // config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(configFilePath);
                xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//appSettings/add[@key='" + Key +"']").Attributes["value"].Value = Value;
                xmlDoc.Save(configFilePath);

                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");

                result = true;
            }
            finally
            { }
            return result;
        }

        private static string GetSetting(string Key, string configFilePath)
        {
            string result = null;
            try
            {
                XmlDocument appSettingsDoc = new XmlDocument();
                appSettingsDoc.Load(configFilePath);
                XmlNode node = appSettingsDoc.SelectSingleNode("//appSettings");
                XmlElement value = (XmlElement)node.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//add[@key='" + Key + "']"));
                result = (value.GetAttribute("value").ToString());
            }
            finally
            { }
            return result;
        }

        private static SecureString ToSecureString(string input)
        {
            SecureString secure = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in input)
            {
                secure.AppendChar(c);
            }
            secure.MakeReadOnly();
            return secure;
        }

        private static string ToInsecureString(SecureString input)
        {
            string returnValue = string.Empty;
            IntPtr ptr = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SecureStringToBSTR(input);
            try
            {
                returnValue = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(ptr);
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ZeroFreeBSTR(ptr);
            }
            return returnValue;
        }

        private static string EncryptString(System.Security.SecureString input)
        {
            byte[] encryptedData = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(
                System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(ToInsecureString(input)), entropy, System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
        }

        private static SecureString DecryptString(string encryptedData)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] decryptedData = System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Unprotect(
                    Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedData),
                    entropy,
                    System.Security.Cryptography.DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

                return ToSecureString(System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(decryptedData));
            }
            catch
            {
                return new SecureString();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}







Update: Action start 14:31:36: Encryption.
MSI (c) (84:40) [14:31:36:525]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\MSIE259.tmp, Entrypoint: m1
InstallShield: Attempting to load through CLR 4 APIs...
InstallShield: Getting meta host...
InstallShield: Enumerating available runtimes...
InstallShield: Highest available runtime: v4.0.30319
InstallShield: Trying to use highest runtime...
InstallShield: Using highest version runtime...
InstallShield: Loading assembly Security.Encryption from resource 4097
InstallShield: Calling method with parameters [(System.String)C:\Program Files (x86)\<Installdir>\<configfilename>.config, (System.String)VWFPassword, (System.String)]
InstallShield: Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\<Installdir>\<configfilename>.config'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver)
   at System.Threading.CompressedStack.runTryCode(Object userData)
   at 

System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
   at System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
   at Security.Encryption.EncrptionHelper.SetSetting(String appSettingKey, String appsettingValue, String configFilePathName)
   at Security.Encryption.EncrptionHelper.SetValue(String configFilePathName, String appSettingKey, String appSettingValue)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethodFast(IRuntimeMethodInfo method, Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeType typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at InstallShield.ClrHelper.CustomActionHelper.CallMethod(EntryPointInfo info)
   at InstallShield.ClrHelper.CustomActionHelper.RunAction(UInt32 installHandle, Int32 entryNumber, Int64 instanceHandle)
InstallShield: Managed code threw an unhandled exception.
```

This is the error I receive after doing all that is mentioned in the screenshots below and doing some R&D. The directory mentioned "C:\Program Files (x86)\\.config" exists when the encryption custiom action is being called but it throws an exception.

Comment: If this is in a Basic MSI project, see  http://stackoverflow.com/a/18334804/89999 . For other project types see some of the other answers on that question.

Comment: xmlDoc.Load(configFilePath); is giving the issue as part of the path {Configfilepathname} cannot be found. Is this isuue related to .net framework compatability of config file?????

Comment: I dont think the updated error is related to installshield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done with following steps:
1- write your required functionality in c# installer class (make sure your are using installer class)

2- Compile and add your dll into installshield (recomended create a separate component for this dll)
3- Select component view -> select above component and go to .Net settings section, set the ".Net Installer class" to true. Set the ".net installer class parameters"

Parameters are passed as key/value pair e.g

```
/targetDirectory="[INSTALLDIR]\"
```

All steps are same, just added screenshots.

- Create a dll with an installer class and your encrypt/decrypt class.
- Add dll and config file to component(above mentioned), if config file is already added to some other component then its fine. no need to add again.
- I have added and retrieved INSTALLDIR variable as argument which is predefined. if you want to receive some input from user (from some custom textboxes) then you will need to define your own variables to store and pass values as arguments.
- Creating dll with installer class and your requred logic for other task [image: Installer class]
- Creating component and adding files[image: component with installer class and dependencies]
- Mark the dll as installer class and pass arguments [image: Passing arguments]

Here goes installer class:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace EncryptionDecryption
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public class InstallerClassDemo : Installer
    {
        private string installationDirectory=string.Empty;
        private string testString=string.Empty ;

        public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            base.Install(stateSaver);

            try
            {
                //For testing purpose only.. work only in debug mode when pdb files are deployed as well.
                //Debugger.Break();

                installationDirectory = Context.Parameters["INSTALLDIR"];

                //I believe, the config file must be located in the installation directory if so, then use the following way to compute path

                string configFilePath = Path.Combine(installationDirectory, "myConfigFile.config");
                EncrptionHelper.SetValue(configFilePath, "testKey", "testValue");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

        }

        protected override void OnCommitted(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.OnCommitted(savedState);
        }

        public override void Uninstall(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)
        {
            base.Uninstall(savedState);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say Needo... I changed the .net installer class to true and im finding difficulty in setting .net class parameters. How can this be done? Screenshots may help a bit And secondly, Should I add the method Install in the .net code???

Comment: Could you please elaborate on /port=[PORT_VARIABLE] /targetDirectory="[INSTALLDIR]\" according to the script I mentioned and also on the installer class which you gave me as example.

Comment: I would strongly suggest avoiding installer classes. The only way they indicate errors is with a message box, and they are often fragile enough to do so with alarming frequency in the field.

Comment: @Michael Urman Message boxes from .net would not work in installshield I suppose. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Bala The problem is that instead of logging, and instead of following UILevel, InstallUtilLib.dll will always put up modal dialogs in response to error conditions. This breaks silent installs, and may look bad in full UI ones. With other approaches (including InstallShield's) this does have to occur. I don't believe InstallShield prevents message boxes, but it does not force them either.

Comment: Agreed with @Michael, but I found often using installer class is helpful to achieve desired functionality, since there are not better/reliable workarounds to such custom needs so, I prefer to go with installer class. You may go to WiX or other flexible option if you have lots of such customization otherwise, having a such workaround is fine to proceed.

Comment: Thanks Micheal and needo. Investigating on that.

Answer (score 0):

I think installshield cannot (or need extra work) for read your assemblies, but you can run simple console application which consume your assemblies from installscript and passing parameter from installshield.

Create simple console application

Include console application on Support Files

Copy to installation folder or assemblies location, so console application can access your assemblies

Launch from installscript using launchappandwait

If consoleapp.exe not use anymore, just delete it.

Comment: Sumantri, How can I do this? Can you help me out with the changes in my code?

Comment: While your technique will work, there are multiple ways in InstallShield to work with managed code. See my and other answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18334804/89999